# Retopo Sculpt Selecting Unwanted Vertices

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

[image: Retopo pulling unwanted vertices]I'm having issues with blender selecting vertices that I can't see and projecting them through the other side.  Is there a setting where I can make it not allow selecting through my sculpt during the retopo process?

Here is an example of what this is doing. Of course, I can't work in wireframe because its too hard to see my vertices.

Comment: is your mesh supposed to be symmetrical?

Comment: Yes its symmetrical.

Comment: if only 1 side has been damaged, you can try to symmetrize it on the +/- axis

Comment: I don't have issues with the damage I can fix that -- I just want to know if there is way to change the reference model's wireframe color.  I can barely see what I'm doing in wireframe mode because the dynotopo is so cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open user preferences (file menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) go in theme tab, select 3D View and change the colors

[image: User pref]

Comment: OMG Thank You Purple on Purple was killing me!!!